# Utilizar animation e keyframe em makeStyles do material ui

Tags: css, react, material-ui

Estou tentando utilizar keyframes em makestyles do material ui, porem não surge efeitos. O Objetivo e fazer que o botão fique pulsando. O que há de errado no meu código? Isto foi o que eu consegui evoluir utilizando um exemplo do code-pen, porem em html e css.[exemplo no code-pen, só que em html e css.](https://codepen.io/seansean11/pen/dhwzj)

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

export const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  button: {
    color: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
    background: 'rgb(255, 121, 46)',
    animation: 'pulse 1.5s infinite',
    '&:hover': {
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(242, 101, 22)',
    },
  },
  '@keyframes pulse': {
    '0%': {
      transform: 'scale(0.95)',
      boxShadow: '0 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)',
    },
    '70%': {
      transform: 'scale(1)',
      boxShadow: '0 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
    },
    '100%': {
      transform: 'scale(0.95)',
      boxShadow: '0 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
    },
  },
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Depois de alguns esforço em vão com makeStyles, consegui realizar utilizando o styled-components como uma opção, pois ja estou utilizando esta dependência para outros componentes. Segue o código utilizando o keyframes no styled components.

```
// Keyframes de pulse
const rotate = keyframes`
  from {
    transform: scale(0.95);
  }

  to {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
`;

export const PulseButton = styled.div`
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid rgb(255, 121, 46);
  animation: ${rotate} 0.5s linear infinite;
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #ff792e;
`;
```